# How to select the following things from psql table?

Tags: sql, export-to-csv, psql

[image]I'm using Postgres to parse some data. I have a SQL table called `person_roles` within a database called Congress. This `person_roles` table contains the following columns:

- person_id (each id is a unique person),
- type (Senator or Representative),
- start_date (the date this person starting to serve in the congress, e.g. 1789-03-04 or e.g. 2015-01-06),
- end_date (the date this person ending to serve in the congress, e.g. 1791-03-03, or e.g. 2021-01-03),
- state (which US state does this person serve in his/her term)
- party (Democrat, Republican, and many other parties; note that there are 4228 people for total whose parties are neither Democrat nor Republican, from 1789 to 2015.)

I want to parse this SQL table and get the following output. Then I want to export such results to a csv file.

My desired output table should have the following columns:

- Year (starting from 1789 and ending in 2015: 1789, 1790, ..., 2014, 2015)
- Number (or count) of total Democratic persons (both senators and representatives) for EACH YEAR for all the states
- Number (or count) of total Republican persons (both senators and representatives) for EACH YEAR for all the states
- Number (or count) of other parties' persons (both senators and representatives) for EACH YEAR for all the states

Since there are 227 years from 1789 to 2015, my desired output table should have 227 rows.

Note that for each year, e.g. 1996, as long as a person's start_date is in this year or before this year (e.g.<=1996-12-31), AND his/her end_date is in this year or after this year (e.g.>=1996-01-02) AND his/her start_date <= end_date, then this person would be counted as a Congress member who serves in this year (e.g. 1996).

I know how to find the number of Democrats or Republicans or Other Parties for a given year in this table. Basically, for example, if I type the following command in congress=#

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberdem
FROM person_roles
WHERE party = 'Democrat'
  AND start_date <= '1996-12-31'
  AND end_date >= '1996-01-02'
  AND start_date <= end_date;
```

then I will get the result:

```
numberdem
----------------
             251 
(1 row)
```

Similarly, if I type the following command:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberrep
FROM person_roles
WHERE party = 'Republican'
  AND start_date <= '1996-12-31'
  AND end_date >= '1996-01-02'
  AND start_date <= end_date;
```

then I will get the result:

```
numberrep
----------------
             291
(1 row)
```

If I type:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberother
FROM person_roles
WHERE party <>  'Republican'
  AND party <>  'Democrat'
  AND start_date <= '1996-12-31'
  AND end_date >= '1996-01-02'
  AND start_date <= end_date;
```

then I will get the result:

```
numberother 
-----------------
                  2
(1 row)
```

However, I do not know how to get a result table that consists of 4 columns where the 1st column gives the year (each year from 1789 to 2015), the 2nd column gives the number of Democrats (numberdum) of each specific year from 1789 to 2015, the 3rd column gives the number of Republicans (numberrep) of each specific year from 1789 to 2015, and the 4th column gives the number of Other Parties (numberother) of each specific year from 1789 to 2015. Eventually, I want to export this SQL output table of 227 rows (because there are 227 years from 1789 to 2015) and 4 columns to a csv file.

How can I achieve such task with SQL command? If this task is not durable with SQL, should I export all the data from the table person_roles and export that to an Excel csv and parse that Excel file instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to duplicate the person for each year they served in, and then group by that so you can count them in each year. Then to turn the counts into columns, you can sum a conditional statement that looks for the value you want to count. Something like:

```
select 
  year, 
  sum(case when party = 'Republican' then 1 else 0 end) as republicans, 
  sum(case when party = 'Democrat' then 1 else 0 end) as democrats, 
  sum(case when party <> 'Republican' and party <> 'Democrat' then 1 else 0 end) as other
from person_roles p
join generate_series(1789,2015) as s(year)
  on year between date_trunc('year', start_date) 
                  and date_trunc('year', end_date)
group by year;
```

Comment: Hi @EvilPuppetMaster, thank you very much! I understand your logic for this query, but when I run this SQL scrip in a shell, it gives me the following error: operator does not exist: integer >= timestamp with time zone. Line8: on year between date_trunc('year', start_date) HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.           How can we fix that? Thanks!

Comment: btw I just added a screenshot picture about the original SQL table "person_roles" to my problem description.

Comment: Just fixed the bug. If I change date_trunc('year', start_date) to date_part('year', start_date), it would work then. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes of course, typo, sorry about that. The perils of writing sql blind with no data to test on! :-)